# Gulp issue - TypeError: sass is not a function

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I have changed my Gulp file over to use Dart SASS with `gulp-sass` after node-sass has been deprecated.

However, it appears I am struggling to actually get it working.

I have set up my gulp file function to use it exactly like the [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) page describes. The only difference is that I am using it in a `series` rather than directly as demonstrated.

```
function scss () {
    return src(`${__dirname}/.../*.scss`)
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle : 'expanded', cache : '/tmp/sass-cache'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer() ]))
        .pipe(dest('System/cache'));
}
```

With my series call being:

```
exports.default = series(deleteDirs, createDirs, scss, build, compile, preview);
```

When I run `gulp` I am getting:

```
Starting 'scss'...
'scss' errored after 8.19 ms
TypeError: sass is not a function
    at scss (/.../gulpfile.js:98:15)
```

node version: 10.13.0
npm version: 6.4.1
nvm version: 0.35.3 (I did `nvm use 10` before this)

I did use an older version of npm as I saw a post earlier stating that newer versions can have issues with these things.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the sass compiler to use dart-sass instead of the default node-sass like this:

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
sass.compiler = require('sass');
```

Or for version 5 of gulp-sass:

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

Comment: second line worked for me. Thanks for being in this world.